# Permutation with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics

how many different four letter words can be formed from the word "ENHANCEMENT" if the first and last letters is A and T respectively.

i am confused.Do we need to include A and T in 2 letters?

possible positions: _ _ 
with repition so 11 * 11 [do we need to eliminate E-3 times N-3 times...]

$^{11}P_2$ or $^9P_2$?
I don't get the concept. [Beginner]

Can someone help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we really only need to count the $2$-letter words that we will stick in the middle, between A and T.

Apart from A and T, which are not available, we have, I think, $3$ E's, $3$ N's, and $1$ each of H, C, and M.

It is best I think to forget temporarily about ${}_nP_k$ and ${}_nC_k$, and just count. We have $5$ different letters.

First count the $2$-letter words that have **distinct** letters. The first letter can be picked in $5$ ways, and for each way the second can be picked in $4$ ways, for a total of $20$.

Then there are the  $2$-letter words EE and NN. That's it, a total of $22$.

The $(5)(4)$ that we got could have been written as ${}_5P_2$. However, it is best to do things concretely, particularly when numbers are small.  Then you retain control over what's going on.

Comment: Don't we need to include A and T within 2 Positions?

Comment: @Dineshkumar: We have no choice, must put A in front and T in back. So the only issue is what we will stick in the middle. That's a $2$-letter string. So it is the $2$-letter strings that we need to count.

Comment: Thanks. any resources[links] to learn permutations which covers all?

Comment: I cannot think of any web source I am familiar with. Khan Academy has some videos (free access). Mainly one has to do lots of problems.